# How to pass ion-item values to a function

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am trying to pass values...I have this items list:

```
<ion-list id="items_list">
    
    <ion-item  *ngFor="let item of items_prods" (click)="callSettingsPage('{{item.ID}}', '{{item.State}}')">
        <ion-item value="{{item.ID}}" >ID : {{item.ID}}<br/>STAT : {{item.State}}</ion-item>
    </ion-item>

</ion-list>
```

and in this piece of code I have a (click) method where I call a function which should go to the other tab page:

```
    callSettingsPage(id:string, state:string) {
        this.myService.IdProd = id.toString();
        this.myService.stateProd = state.toString();
        alert("id: " + this.myService.IdProd + " - state: " + this.myService.stateProd);
    }
```

But how I could pass those Id and State values to the function?

Thanks! Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try without `{{` and `'` (single quotes) because the `'` tells angular to treat the inside value as `string`

```
<ion-list id="items_list">
    
    <ion-item  *ngFor="let item of items_prods" (click)="callSettingsPage(item.ID,item.State)">
        <ion-item value="{{item.ID}}" >ID : {{item.ID}}<br/>STAT : {{item.State}}</ion-item>
    </ion-item>

</ion-list>
```